# Dynamic mount point for Shared Volume Containers

Tags: docker

Is there any way currently to create a dynamically named volume during Docker's build process? I'd like to see something like:

```
sudo docker run -e MOUNT_POINT="/path/to/mount" module/sub-module
```

and then in the Dockerfile have something like:

```
ln -s /internal/path/to/storage $MOUNT_POINT
VOLUME [$MOUNT_POINT]
```

This would allow the highly valuable `volumes-from` directive to be used but each storage container built could have a variant mount point (and avoid colliding with a consumer who wanted to consume more than one data-volume-container).

Any ideas would be VERY welcome.

Comment: Why the symlink?

If it's only a symlink you want, then you could maybe create it in a script, which you invoke as ENTRYPOINT or CMD.

And then dynamically create the VOLUME when you start your container.

(The script that creates the symlink, ofc starts your application as well.)

Comment: It allows me to store data/content to a consistent place and then dynamically at docker runtime it can allocate the share to whatever directory the Host wants

Comment: AKA, the symlink is *not* the important part but it makes sure that the content is available at the internal mount point (which is dynamically allocated based on a ENV variable passed in during docker runtime).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how one should use volumes.

- You have one container, say your application container for e.g. a database.
- You have another container, say your volumes container actually holding your data.
- You start your volumes container with the volumes parameter `-v`. Here you can name your volume dynamically.
- You start your application container with the option `--volumes-from` using your volumes container.

See the docs for detailed information https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Comment: Yes I understand that Zyndicate. The problem is that the VOLUME declaration in a Dockerfile appears to be static and limits scenarios where you want to create a generic storage container which can be instantiated with various forms of content. That part is fine, it's then a problem that all derivatives of this generic container would share on the SAME share point when using `--volumes-from`. With a standard `-v` share you have the ability to directly specify a host:client mapping but the same is *not* true when using `--volumes-from`.

Comment: @ken - volumes dynamically created with `-v` do follow with `--volumes-from`. Not sure that I understand your use case?

Comment: In the case of the pattern [Data Volume Containers](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container), you would expect to have a non-running container which has persistent storage. That storage can be mounted using `--volumes-from` but unless I'm mistaken not `-v` (which is only for mounting a daemonized/running container).

Comment: The problem comes into being when you have a data consumer which is taking in 2 or more Data Volume Containers ... because the only nomenclature available is `--volumes-from` both storage containers will collide if they are based off the same mount point

Comment: For an example of a generalised storage container take a look at what I'm doing here: https://github.com/lifegadget/docker-locker

Comment: Containers never! should persist data by itself, because they are volatile and should handled like that. That is why you need to mount a volume path into your data container, to have data still available even if the container is gone.

Comment: No that is not true but it is a commonly held belief; take a look at the official documentation ... http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container.